# How to understand which css class is from bootstrap or any other custom stylesheets defined inside project

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The problem i am having is that I can't really understand which classes belong where.

I have got a project which uses bootstrap and some custom stylesheets. So, when some classes are declared for an element then how can I say which classes are from bootstrap and which classes are from any other custom css that we declare?

Is there any way to do this? or even with any IDE?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a bit vague. Are you trying to see where the styles are coming from - whether Bootstrap or your custom style sheet? Not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @disinfor : yap thats what I am trying to figure out. where are the classes coming from? whether bootstrap or custom css.

Comment: inspecting elements using the browser dev tools you can see on the styles (right-side usually) where a given class/id is defined, does that help?

Comment: As @FabioG pointed out, you should use the Inspect tool in your browser. It will list what styles are applied to each element and and what stylesheet they are coming from.

Comment: @FabioG : thanks a lot. it helped.

Comment: @shaon Actually to be more clear which is Bootstrap and which one is your own class, we should always prefix/suffix something to all of our custom classes like prefix something few characters related to your project, company etc throughout the project. In this way, it's more clear to know even just by seeing the code only. eg: your class is ```.customer-form``` then if we prefix ```fit``` then the class name should be ```.fit-customer-form``` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example:

HTML:

```
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css>
</head>

<body>
<b class="text-warning test test2">Hello World</b>
</body>
```

custom CSS

```
  .test2{
   color: blue;
   }

  .test{
   color: red;
  }
```

*text-warning is a bootstrap class, which colors the text yellow.

CSS always takes the style from the latest defined class/id/tag... when they are using the same properties. In this case the property color with the value red from the class "test".
So normally you include in your html-header at first the bootstrap css and then your custom css. With this order your custom css overwrites the bootstrap css. But you can use [!important](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/) in your css style to force your style.